# Thickbox does not show content i Firefox

Tags: jquery, thickbox

Link: http://hedenstedfotoklub.net.dynamicweb.dk/

In the upper grey area there is a little icon which triggers ThickBox.
My only problem is that in Firefox Thickbox doesn't show the content.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link needs to tell thickbox to load the URL in an IFrame. Thickbox strips everything in the URL after 'TB_', this should work.

```
<div id="buttons">
    <a href="/files/templates/extranet/login_uk.htmlTB_iframe=true&width=400&height=220" class="login thickbox" title="Login her">
        Login
    </a>
</div>
```

See the [thickbox docs](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/#examples) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, that's the Iframed content.  But I was using the AJAX content method but that one apparently doesn't work in Firefox.